# Getting could not invode RNFirebaseFirestore.documentSet null No virtual method Set

Tags: react-native-firebase

Please find the attached screenshot for exact error. I'm getting this error when I'm trying to set the data to firestore. Following is the code

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export function initializeFirestore() {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('communities')
        .doc('communityname')
        .collection('members')
        .doc('memberid')
        .set({ field1: 'value1' })
        .then(function(docRef) {})
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error updating userChannel : ', error);
        });
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhIuv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got your answer but, the only workaround I've been seeing is to downgrade firebase-firestore to 17.1.5
in app level Build.gradle file add 
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"`
I got the answer from [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1867#issuecomment-460170050)